# How can I use metadata to put audio files in directory?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I downloaded a directory full of Audio file like

```
0001.wav
0002.wav
...
4555.wav
```

and I also downloaded the dataset.csv  related to these files which contains metadata like the `name` of the sound ( the number before the .wav) and the `label` (exemple: first column is `name`and seconde column is `label`, in the first row I have `0001`  and `Electric_guitar` .

With `pandas`,I sorted all my data by `label` so I created many tables like `Electric_guitar.csv` or `scream.csv` and now I want to classify in differents directories all my audio files using these tables. I search on internet but I didnt find anything that help me, maybe I have trouble to formulate my issues.

How am I supposed to do that?
ty

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas `read_csv` with `dtype=str` to make sure the `name` column will not be interpreted as a number (e.g. where `0009` could become `9`). Use `itertuples` to iterate over rows as namedtuples, don't use [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) in this case since:

> ...iterrows returns a Series for each row, it **does not** preserve dtypes across the rows (dtypes are preserved across columns for DataFrames)

Then, for each row, use [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) to create the folder (if doesn't already exist) using the `label` name as parameter, and finally, move the files to the appropriate label folder with [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename).

Input *sounds.metafile*

```
name,label
00000,talking
00001,talking
00002,drums
00003,eletric_guitar
00004,scream
00005,scream
00006,scream
00007,eletric_guitar
00008,talking
00009,eletric_guitar
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_csv('sounds.metafile', dtype=str)
print(df)

for row in df.itertuples():
    # create a folder for each label
    os.makedirs(f"output/{row.label}", exist_ok=True)
    #  move files
    os.rename(f'audio_files/{row.name}.wav', f'output/{row.label}/{row.name}.wav')
```

*Output* folder structure

```
output
├── drums
│   └── 00002.wav
├── eletric_guitar
│   ├── 00003.wav
│   ├── 00007.wav
│   └── 00009.wav
├── scream
│   ├── 00004.wav
│   ├── 00005.wav
│   └── 00006.wav
└── talking
    ├── 00000.wav
    ├── 00001.wav
    └── 00008.wav
```